# OpenMP and VS 2012 unexpected end-of-file found

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, openmp

I am trying to find why I get an error when I try to run a pi calculation program with openMP.
The code I am using is displayed below, using vs2012 and having set the openMP option in the project. I have successfully run a `hello world` program but I dont understand whats the problem here.

```
#include <omp.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define NUM_THREADS 2

static long num_steps = 100000;
double step;
int main(void)
{
    // Shared variable, updated !
    int i;
    double pi, sum[NUM_THREADS]; 
    step = 1.0/(double) num_steps;

    omp_set_num_threads(NUM_THREADS);

    #pragma omp parallel 
    {   double x;
        int id; 
        id = omp_get_thread_num();
        sum[id]=0.0;
        for (i=id; i< num_steps; i=i+NUM_THREADS){ 
            x = (i+0.5)*step; 
            sum[id] += 4.0/(1.0+x*x); 
        } 
    }
    pi=0.0;
    for(i=0;i<NUM_THREADS;i++){
        pi += sum[i] * step; 
    }
    printf("pi = %f\n",pi);
    return 0;
}
```

So the only error I get is 
`pi.cpp(35): fatal error C1004: unexpected end-of-file found`
Whats going on here? Is it a bug of Visual Studio?
Thanks in advance

*Dont mind the code being inefficient, the problem here is not about the code here but VS2012 and openMP...*

Comment: Your code has a race condition in `i`. You should do `#pragma omp parallel private(i)`

Comment: @Z boson You shouldnt have deleted your answer. It was still useful since you have given a better solution to the code problem. If you want please repost it. It could be helpful for some.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The precompiled header feature is on by default. When it is on every cpp file must have the very first include line like

```
#include "stdafx.h"
```

The compiler is scanning your source file looking for that line, and it ignores everything else until it finds it.  You can turn off precompiled headers in the project properties.

Comment: @Geo I don't understand your question. On the Project menu click Properties then find the Precompiled Header section.

Comment: I mean its not what you have suggested. The precompiled Header has the stdafx.h enabled.

Comment: When it is enabled then you must #include "stdafx.h" at the very top of every source file. The code you posted does not do that.

Comment: I did that as well and I get:`pi.cpp(1): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'stdafx.h': No such file or directory`

Comment: Create a whole new proect (File, New, Project) and select Win32, Win32 Console Application. It will have stdafx.h and stdafx.cpp files, along with a do-nothing _tmain function. It should build as-is without errors.  

Then copy and paste your code into this new project.

Comment: Still the same. It compiled with the header, then when i paste the code and include the stdafx.h I get the same `error unexpected eof found`. I also tried to name `main()` to `_tmain` as in the default code but didnt work... So by all these it seems to have to reinstall or repair something?

Comment: Ok i fixed it. I have 2 `.cpp` files: one with the project name and the other `stdafx.cpp` file. I had to put the code in the `project.cpp` file leave the `stdafx.cpp` as it is (with a header file only) and put all headers and `#define` at the `stdfx.h` file. Thanks for your help. If you want please edit your answer with what i ve said here etc etc for other people that might come across the same problem and I ll accept your answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your question is essentially a duplicated of another one [I answered recently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26382714/parallel-program-using-openmp/26384084#26384084]). Even after you get your code to compile you will find race conditions and false sharing. Instead of giving the same answer let me add something new.

In your code you try and define the chunks for the for loop manual and additionally you also save the partial sum per thread and then merge the result after the parallel section. There is no good reason to do either of these things for what you're doing. But let me give two examples where you need to do this. The only reason I can think of to define the chunks manually is when doing [induction to reduce the number of computations per iteration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19378312/induction-with-openmp-getting-range-values-for-a-parallized-for-loop-in-openmp).

In your case you can change your function to use induction like this:

```
double pi = 0.0;
for(double x=0.5*step; x<max; x+=step) {
    pi += 1.0/(1.0+x*x);
}
pi *= 4*step
```

To do this with OpenMP requires that you define start and end range of the for loop:

```
double pi = 0.0;
#pragma omp parallel reduction(+:pi)
{
    int ithread = omp_get_thread_num();
    int nthreads = omp_get_num_threads();
    int start = ithread*n/nthreads;
    int finish = (ithread+1)*n/nthreads;
    double startx = (start+0.5)*step;
    double finishx = (finish+0.5)*step;
    for(double x=startx; x<finishx; x+=step) {
        pi += 1.0/(1.0+x*x);        
    }       
}
pi *= 4*step;
```

As I already stated, induction is the only case I can think of where you need to do this.

Your code also saves the result of the reduction per thread. The only reason I can think of doing this is if the operation you are doing is not [commutative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutative_property). Matrix multiplication is not commutative as `A*B` is *not equal* to `B*A` in general. But your operation is commutative but let assume it's not.  In that case you could do the reduction like this

```
double pi = 0.0;
int nthreads;
double *ppi;
#pragma omp parallel
{
    double pi_private = 0.0;
    int ithread = omp_get_thread_num();
    #pragma single
    {
        nthreads = omp_get_num_threads();
        ppi = new double[nthreads];
    } 
    #pragma omp for
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        double x = (i+0.5)*step;
        pi_private += 1.0/(1.0+x*x);
    }
    ppi[ithread] = pi_private;
}
for(int i=0; i<nthreads; i++) {
    pi += ppi[i];
}
pi *= 4*step;
delete[] ppi;
```

Incidentally, in order to do a reduction the operation needs to be associative. But floating point arithmetic is not strictly associative. When doing reductions with floating point arithmetic one has to accept that the result may not be reproducible.

In any case the simple thing to do in your case is:

```
double pi = 0.0;
#pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:pi)
for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
    double x = (i+0.5)*step;
    pi += 1.0/(1.0+x*x);
}
pi *= 4*step;
```

Here is the full code

```
include <stdio.h>
#include <omp.h>

void foo(int n) {
    double step = 1.0/n;
    double max = (0.5+n)*step;
    double pi = 0.0;
    for(double x=0.5*step; x<max; x+=step) {
        pi += 1.0/(1.0+x*x);
    }
    pi *= 4*step;
    printf("pi %f\n", pi);
}

void foo2(int n) {
    double step = 1.0/n;
    double pi = 0.0;
    #pragma omp parallel reduction(+:pi)
        {
        int ithread = omp_get_thread_num();
        int nthreads = omp_get_num_threads();
            int start = ithread*n/nthreads;
            int finish = (ithread+1)*n/nthreads;
        double startx = (start+0.5)*step;
        double finishx = (finish+0.5)*step;
        for(double x=startx; x<finishx; x+=step) {
            pi += 1.0/(1.0+x*x);
            //printf("%d %f\n", ithread, x);    
        }
    }
    pi *= 4*step;
    printf("pi %f\n", pi);
}

void foo3(int n) {
    double step = 1.0/n;
        double pi = 0.0;
    int nthreads;
    double *ppi;
    #pragma omp parallel
    {
        double pi_private = 0.0;
        int ithread = omp_get_thread_num();
        #pragma single
        {
            nthreads = omp_get_num_threads();
            ppi = new double[nthreads];
        }   
        #pragma omp for
            for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
            double x = (i+0.5)*step;
            pi_private += 1.0/(1.0+x*x);
        }
        ppi[ithread] = pi_private;
    }
    for(int i=0; i<nthreads; i++) {
        pi += ppi[i];
    }
    pi *= 4*step;
    printf("pi %f\n", pi);
}

void foo4(int n) {
    double step = 1.0/n;
        double pi = 0.0;
    #pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:pi)
        for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        double x = (i+0.5)*step;
        pi += 1.0/(1.0+x*x);
    }
    pi *= 4*step;
    printf("pi %f\n", pi);
}

int main() {
    foo(1<<20);
    foo2(1<<20);
    foo3(1<<20);
    foo4(1<<20);
}
```

Comment: @Z boson Thanks for the answer but... the problem is not about weather the code is efficient, which is not, but why it wont compile. In the code that i wrote above, is it somehow connected to the error tha i mentioned?

Comment: @GeoPapas, your code is not just inefficient, it's wrong. You have a race condition in `i`. After you make `i` private you will find your code is slow due to false sharing. So as I said even after you get your code to compile you will discover other problems.

Comment: @Z boson I agree with you but the question wasnt about the code ;) Thanks for the answer though and for the better implementation.